# Warning format specifies type int but the argument has type long

Tags: c

I cannot find how to fix this, And how to get an output like:  `4! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24` instead `4 * 3  * 2 * 1 * =24`.

> ```
> warning: format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
>      printf("%ld",i);`
> ```

I'm new in code and totally stuck:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long int factorial(int);

int main() {
   int numb;
   printf("Enter number =");
   scanf("%d", &numb);
   printf("=%ld\n", factorial(numb));
}

long int factorial(int x) {
     int i = x, n = 1;
     while (i > 0) {
         printf("%ld", i);
         if (i > 0)
            printf("*");
         n *= i;
         i--;
    }
    return n;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Format `%d` has to be used for `int`. `%ld` is for `long int`

Comment: For the order, initialise `i = 1` and stop when `i  >  n`

Comment: Make `n` a `long int` as now the factorial is still limited to the integer range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from the mismatch between the `"%ld"` conversion specifier, which expects an expression of type `long int` and the actual type of `i` which is `int`. Just use `"%d"` instead.

To print the factors in increasing order, you can change the loop direction, make `i` run from `1` to `n` inclusively.

Also note that `n` should be defined as a `long int` to benefit from the expanded range if `long` is indeed larger than `int`, which is the case on 64-bit linux and OS/X but not on legacy systems such as Microsoft Windows.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long int factorial(int);

int main() {
   int numb;
   printf("Enter number: ");
   if (scanf("%d", &numb) == 1) {
       printf("%d! = ", numb));
       printf(" = %ld\n", factorial(numb));
    }
    return 0;
}

long int factorial(int x) {
    long int n = 1;
    int i;
    printf("1");  // always print 1
    for (i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
        printf(" * %d", i); // print other factors
        n *= i;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
long int factorial(int);

int main() {
   long int numb;
   printf("Enter number =");
   scanf("%ld", &numb);
   printf("=%ld\n", factorial(numb));
}

long int factorial(int x) {
     long int i = 1, n = 1;
     while (i <= x) {
         printf("%ld", i);
         if(i<x)
         printf("*");
         n *= i;
         i++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Just adjusted your code.

i goes like `i=1,2,3,4` ...until `x`. `n=1,2,6,24,...`